# Android startActivity with extraparams of type Arraylist

Tags: android

I am trying to pass Arraylist as an argument to startActivity API. I can see array is correctly populated but on the receiving side, Arraylist size becomes zero; Here is my code. Please suggest possible reason for that.

```
private void downloadImage(String urlStr) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Downloading CSV file from " + urlStr);
    final String url = urlStr;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChartScreen.class);
    final ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            InputStream in = null;
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 1;
            try {
                in = openHttpConnection(url);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                try {
                    String csvLine;
                    while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
                        resultList.add(row);
                    }
                }catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
                }finally {
                        in.close();
               }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("Data", resultList);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

== Receiving Activity ==

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
    String msg = "Android : ";
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null){
        ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("Data");       // size of arr is zero here
    }
```

Comment: make sure that before pass array size not be zero

Comment: you have started the thread but you are not waiting for it to complete.that is why you activity is started with zero sized array list.

Comment: yes consider @piyush point

Comment: Is a `String[]` Parcelable?

Comment: For this `AsyncTask` will be best option, just do your thread related thing inside `doinbackground` , get result at `onostexecute` and start new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this if you using thread.I suggest to use async task

```
  private void downloadImage(String urlStr) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Downloading CSV file from " + urlStr);
        final String url = urlStr;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChartScreen.class);
        final ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList();
       Thread downloadImage = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                InputStream in = null;
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = 1;
                try {
                    in = openHttpConnection(url);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    try {
                        String csvLine;
                        while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
                            resultList.add(row);
                        }
                    }catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
                    }finally {
                            in.close();
                   }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
      downloadImage.join();
   **//**Start activity with a new task flag or you will get error****
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList("Data", resultList);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(intent);
    }





     Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList("Data", resultList);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(intent);
```